# in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just created a laravel project but could not access the `route`

route :

```
Route::get('a', function () {
    echo "aaaaa";
});
```

link: http://localhost/www/onlineshop/a

error message : **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

```
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

That's how a basic `route` is defined in Laravel 5

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

from [Laravel 5.0 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#basic-routing)

Also, make sure you defined your route in `app/Http/routes.php`.